# Replace existing folder with mv command

Tags: macos, mac, bash, mv

Apologies if this question has already been asked, I couldn't find anything…

Lets say I want to replace 'oldstuff' with 'newstuff'. Basically re-naming to replace.
I try using this command:

```
mv ~/newstuff ~/oldstuff
```

But that only moves the folder 'newstuff' into the 'oldstuff' folder.

How would I replace 'oldstuff' with 'newstuff'?

I am running OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `~/oldstuff` does not exist,

```
mv ~/newstuff ~/oldstuff
```

will rename `newstuff` to `oldstuff`. If it exists, it will move `newstuff` into `oldstuff`.

So, to answer your question, first remove `~/oldstuff` (or rename it to `olderstuff`, see this question again on how to do it), then use the `mv` command as you did.

Comment: oldstuff does exist though. That's the issue, is there anyway to do it without issuing a delete command first?

Comment: @JacobLukeWood: There cannot be two directories with the same name. If you want to move the contents into an existing directory, use `mv newstuff/* oldstuff` (could get more complicated if `.files` are involved).

Comment: I ended up doing what you said using the wildcard (*) with it, thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

Another solution would be to use rsync.  (Be careful with the trailing slashes.  They are important).

This will copy everything in newstuff into oldstuff.

```
rsync -av ~/newstuff/ ~/oldstuff
```

And, the code below will copy everything in newstuff into oldstuff, and delete anything in oldstuff which is not in newstuff.

```
rsync -av --delete ~/newstuff/ ~/oldstuff
```

Note that neither of these commands will do anything to the files in ~/newstuff though.  If you want to delete them, you'll have to do the `rm` command separately.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options.

```
mv ~/newstuff/* ~/oldstuff
rmdir ~/newstuff
mv ~/oldstuff ~/newstuff
```

and

```
mv ~/oldstuff ~/ancientstuff
mv ~/newstuff ~/oldstuff
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
mv -f folder1/* folder2 && rmdir folder1
```

Will move everything in `folder1`, including files and directories to `folder2`.

`-f`: do not prompt before overwriting equivalent to `--reply=yes`.

[mv man page](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_mv.htm).